# How to integrate i18n-js in React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, internationalization, expo

I'm having issues instantiating I18n in my Expo app. The TL;DR of the problem is that components that need the translations are rendered before

```
Expo.Util.getLocaleAsync()
```

returns and sets the locale. I can't figure out how to best set it up. As of now, I have a file for my instance of I18n, which I then import and use everywhere else in my app. It looks something like this:

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';
import english from './resources/strings/en';
import danish from './resources/strings/da';

I18n.defaultLocale = 'en-GB';
I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.initAsync = async () => {
  var locale = 'en-GB';
  try {
    locale = await Expo.Util.getCurrentLocaleAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error getting locale: ' + error);
  }

  I18n.locale = locale ? locale.replace(/_/, '-') : '';
};

I18n.translations = {
  en: english,
  da: danish,
};

export default I18n;
```

Then, in my root app component, I do the following:

import I18n from './src/i18n';

```
class App extends React.Component {
  async componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Current locale (main1): ' + I18n.currentLocale());
    try {
      await I18n.initAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error setting locale ' + error);
    }

    console.log('Current locale (main2): ' + I18n.currentLocale());
  }

  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

The logs state the expected values - first the default locale, and then the updated locale in main2. The problem is that the child views are rendered with the first locale before the change is made, and I don't understand why?

I can't figure out a better way to do this, any ideas/tips would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: After some more searching, it seems that making componentWillMount() async does not necessarily make it wait for the await to return, as Flow indicated for me. See discussion in this issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1803  . This would mean that this strategy is not viable, and it would have to be done otherwise. How, I do not know yet :-)

Comment: Do you have a working solution? Can you post an update?

Comment: We ended up never doing it anyway for that project, but check out https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/ @Yossi

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

In `main.js`:

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appIsReady: false,
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await I18n.initAsync();
    this.setState({appIsReady: true});
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.appIsReady) {
      return (
          <AppLoading />
      );
    }
    return ( 
      <RootComponent>
    );
  )
```

and in some component:

```
import I18n from '../i18n';

  render() {
    return (
         <View>
           <Text>{I18n.t('favorites')}</Text>
           <Text>{I18n.locale}</Text>
         </View>
    )
  }
```

And from the root dir I created `i18n/index.js`:

```
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

I18n.fallbacks = true; // let 'en-GB' fallback to 'en' if not found
I18n.translations = {
  'en': require('./en.json'),
  'nl': require('./nl.json'),
}

export default I18n;
```

my initial Dutch translation file in `i18n/nl.json`:

```
{
  favorites: 'Jouw Favorieten',
}
```

I have this in my `package.json`:

```
"react-native-i18n": "git+https://github.com/xcarpentier/ex-react-native-i18n.git",
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution for you: https://github.com/xcarpentier/ex-react-native-i18n

Comment: Hey Matty, thanks for the suggestion :-) I did find that same repo, but 1. It pretty much uses the same approach, and would therefore have the same problem, and 2. I would prefer not using a fork of a fork for my project, but rather figure out how to better implement the original, more well-supported project. Looking at his code in index.js, he's doing exactly the same thing AFAIK :-)

Comment: So you've made your `componentWillMount()` asynchronous, and you're calling await before the `setLocale()` ?

Comment: Correct, updated the question to show how the code is called :-)

Answer (score 1):

in react native expo it's easy.

1. **install** and **import**

   expo install expo-localization

**app.js**

```js
import { I18nManager } from 'react-native';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
```

2. Create an object with supported language.

```js
i18n.translations = {
  en: { addPrice: 'add Price Here', subTax: 'Sub Tax -' },
  ar: { addPrice: 'ادخل السعر هنا', subTax: 'قبل ضريبة - ' },
};

// Set the locale once at the starting app.

i18n.locale = Localization.locale;

// When a value is missing from a language it'll fallback 
// to another language with the key present.

i18n.fallbacks = true;

//don't change app dir to rtl. 
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

3. use it Everywhere

```js
<TouchableOpacity >
    <Text>{i18n.t('subTax')}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```